# Were there proofs of the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem without using maximal functions?

Tags: mathematics, real-analysis

Is there a proof of the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem that does not involve the Hardy-Littlewood Maximal Function? For example, did Lebesgue prove it?

If there is such a proof, where can I find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original proof appears in [Lebesgue's Lecons sur l'integration et la recherche des fonctions primitives, Paris, 1904](https://archive.org/details/leconsdiscontinues00bairrich/page/n9/mode/2up), freely available if you read French. He only considered continuous monotone functions. Young gave a proof without assuming continuity in 1911, and in 1932 Riesz gave an elementary proof for the continuous case using his "Rising Sun Lemma". In 1965 Austin gave a non-elementary geometric proof that requires intricate measure theory including the measurability of the Dini derivatives. Botsko gives a general elementary proof in [American Mathematical Monthly
Vol. 110, No. 9 (Nov., 2003), pp. 834-838](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3647803), and according to him all other proofs use the Vitali Covering Theorem (in proving the estimate for Hardy-Littlewood Maximal Function, for instance), or the Lebesgue Density Theorem.

Comment: +1.  My answer would have been: to prove it without the maximal function, use the Vitali covering theorem.